# Go: time.sleep and memory usage

Tags: memory, time, go, sleep

When running the code below, the program starts at around 1.5M and then gradually grows until 6.4M. I'm wondering why. 
Removing *time.sleep* fixes the issue.

Is there a way to use the for-select pattern with a default and sleep some time in the default without any mem change?

Calling *runtime.GC()* after the sleep does fix the issue. Can we achieve the same thing without having to call the GC ?

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
            //some work
        default:
            //some work
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Same with :

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
        case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 10):
        }
    }
}
```

---

After some time researching, I achieved it with the following code. Still wonder why time.sleep increases mem usage?

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)
    timer := time.NewTimer(0)
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
        default:
            timer.Reset(time.Millisecond * 1)
            <-timer.C
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Time.Sleep does not "increase memory". Memory consumption or usage, what actually is used, when or what memory is released or returned to the OS is very complicated.

Comment: Using time.Timer did the trick. I believe you when you say it's complicated.

Comment: Just watch the output of gctrace to see what the GC is doing. Sleep requires a small allocation, and those eventually need to be cleaned up. If you're doing any real "work", it probably requires some allocations which need to be clean up. The GC isn't instantaneous, it waits until some threshold is reached before it is run, and hence the heap grows somewhat before leveling off.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some time researching, I achieved it with the following code.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)
    timer := time.NewTimer(0)
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
        default:
            timer.Reset(time.Millisecond * 1)
            <-timer.C
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a timeout using a `select` and receive from `<-time.After()`:

```
select {
  case res := <-c:
    fmt.Println("do some work")
  case <-time.After(time.Second * 1):
    fmt.Println("timeout")
}
```

In case you want to understand how your program is utilizing memory you can do profiling. [Here](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) is a nice article about this topic.

Comment: removing the `default:` and using instead `case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 10):` still increase the mem usage over time. I guess it's something internal to the time pkg.